# vue js : register third party component localy instead of globaly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a vue js app (Inertia js) and I installed many third party libraries.
every library I may use one or two times, so I need to register them localy in the component where I need them.

The problem is the library documentation registers the component globaly and it works, but I do not want them to be global!, it will make the app.js file so large.

So, I tried to register them localy but it does not work.

This is an example of one of them: [vcalendar.io](https://vcalendar.io)

inside **app.js**

```
import VCalendar from 'v-calendar';
import 'v-calendar/dist/style.css';
```

...

```
app.use(VCalendar)
```

inside **my component**

```
<v-calendar />
```

and this works fine.

I tried to do this in **my component**

```
    <template>
      <v-calendar />
      <VCalendar />
    </template>

    <script>
    import VCalendar from 'v-calendar';
    import 'v-calendar/dist/style.css';
    
    export default {
       components: {
         VCalendar
       }
    }
    </script>
```

but it does not work and the console has no errors.

As I mentined, this is one of many libraries do the same thing. I can use them only if I register them globaly.

**Is there a way to make it work when I register the component localy?**

Comment: It's safe to assume that the lib does some other setup job else besides registering global comp when being used as a plugin `app.use(VCalendar)`. If the docs don't mention local usage and it doesn't work out of the box like that, you can be quite sure that's the case. Even if it's possible to make it work locally, this requires to dig into sources and use the lib in an undocumented way

Comment: yes, I thinks thats it, some libraries mentions both ways to register thier components and some others does not. I asked to see if there a way to do it may be I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

That `VCalendar` is supposed to be used as `app.use(VCalendar)` suggests that it's Vue plugin, i.e. an object with `install` method, so it's incorrect to use it as a component.

Library components should explicitly support local use and not rely on global plugin setup. If it's documented that local use is supported and components are publiclu exported then this can be done. This is what [the documentation shows](https://vcalendar.io/installation.html). In the latest version components are available from main entry point:

```
import { Calendar, DatePicker } 'v-calendar'

export default {
  components: {
    Calendar,
    DatePicker
  }
  ...
```

Comment: this does not work because this is for vue 2 and I am using vue 3

Comment: I see. You need to check the package yourself in such cases. It can be seen that comps are now named exports and shouldn't be imported from internal modules https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/blob/v3.0.0-alpha.8/src/index.ts#L19